# c/c++: How can I know the size of used flash memory?

Tags: c++, c, flash, memory, out-of-memory

I recently faced flash overflow problem. After doing some optimization in code, I saved some flash memory and executed software successfully. I want to how much flash memory is saved through my changes. Please let me know how can I check for used flash / available flash memory. Also I want to how much flash is utilized by particular function/file.

Below mentioned are some info about my developing environment. 
 - Avr microcontroller with 64 k ram and 512 K flash.
 - Using freeRtos.
 - Using GNU C++ compiler.
 - Using AVRATJTAGEICE for programming and Debugging.

Please let me know the solution.

Regards,
Jagadeep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please let me know the solution.

Sorry, there's no **the solution**! You've gotta getting through what's linked to your final ELF, and decide if it was linked by intend, or unwanted default.

> Please let me know how can I check for used flash / available flash memory.

That primarily depends on your actual target hardware platform, so you have to manage to get your `.text` section fitting in there.

> Also I want to how much flash is utilized by particular function/file.

The `nm` tool of the GCC binutils provides detailed information about any (global) symbol found in an ELF file and the space it occupies in it's associated section. You'll just need to `grep` the results for particular functions/classes/namespaces (best demangled!) to accumulate section type and symbol filtered outputs for analysis.

That's the approach, I've been using for a little tool called [`nmalyzr`](https://github.com/makulik/nmalyzr). Sorry to say, as it stands on the GIT repo, its not really working as intended (I've got working versions, that aren't pushed back).

---

In general, it's a good strategy to chase for code that has `#include <iostream>` statements (no matter if `std::cout` or alike are used or not, static instances are provided!), or unwanted newlib/libstdc++ bindings as for e.g. default exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

GCC's `size` program is what you're looking for.

---

`size` can be passed the full compiled `.elf` file. It will, by default, output something like this:

```sh
$ size linked-file.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  11228     112    1488   12828    321c linked-file.elf
```

This is saying:

> There are `11228` bytes in the `.text` "section" of this file. This is generally for functions.
>   There are `112` bytes of **initialized data**: global variables in the program with initial values.
>   There are `1488` bytes of **uninitialized data**: global variables without initial values.

`dec` is simply the sum of the previous 3 values: `11228 + 112 + 1488 = 12828`.
`hex` is simply the hexadecimal representation of the `dec` value: `0x321c == 12828`.

For embedded systems, generally `dec` needs to be smaller than the flash size of your target device (or the available space on the device).

It is generally sufficient to simply watch the `dec` or `text` outputs of GCC's `size` command to monitor the size of your compiled code over time. A large jump in size often indicates a poorly implemented new feature or `constexpr` that are not getting compiled away. (Don't forget `function-sections` and `data-sections`).

**Note**: For AVR's, you'll want to use `avr-size` for checking the linked size of AVR `.elf` files. `avr-size` takes an extra argument of the target chip and will automatically calculate the percentage of used flash for your chosen chip.

---

GCC's `size` also works directly on intermediate object files.

This is particularly useful if you want to check the compiled size of functions.

You should see something like this excerpt:

```sh
$ size -A main.cpp.o
main.cpp.o  :
section                                                                size   addr
.group                                                                    8      0
.group                                                                    8      0
.text                                                                     0      0
.data                                                                     0      0
.bss                                                                      0      0
.text._Z8sendByteh                                                        8      0
.text._ZN3XMC5IOpin7setModeENS0_4ModeE                                   64      0
.text._ZN7NamSpac6OptionIN5Clock4TimeEEmmEi                              76      0
.text.Default_Handler                                                    24      0
.text.HardFault_Handler                                                  16      0
.text.SVC_Handler                                                        16      0
.text.PendSV_Handler                                                     16      0
.text.SysTick_Handler                                                    28      0
.text._Z5errorPKc                                                         8      0
.text._ZN7NamSpac5Motor2goEi                                            368      0
.text._ZN7NamSpac5Motor3getEv                                            12      0
.rodata.cst1                                                              1      0
.text.startup.main                                                      632      0
.text._ZN7NamSpac7Program3runEv                                         380      0
.text._ZN7NamSpac8Position4tickEv                                        24      0
.text.startup._GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN7NamSpac7displayE                       292      0
.init_array                                                               4      0
.bss._ZN5Debug9formatterE                                                 4      0
.rodata._ZL10dispDigits                                                   8      0
.bss.position                                                             4      0
.bss.motorState                                                           4      0
.bss.count                                                                4      0
.rodata._ZL9diameters                                                    20      0
.bss._ZN7NamSpac8diameterE                                               16      0
.bss._ZN5Debug3pinE                                                      12      0
.bss._ZN7NamSpac7displayE                                                24      0
.rodata.str1.4                                                          153      0
.rodata._ZL12dispSegments                                                32      0
.bss._ZL16diametersDisplay                                               10      0
.bss.loadAggregate                                                        4      0
.bss.startCount                                                           4      0
.bss._ZL15runtimesDisplay                                                10      0
.bss._ZN7NamSpac7runtimeE                                                16      0
.bss.startTime                                                            4      0
.rodata._ZL8runtimes                                                     20      0
.comment                                                                111      0
.ARM.attributes                                                          49      0
Total                                                                  2494
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `size` command from binutils on the generated elf file. As you seem to use an AVR chip, use `avr-size`.

To get the size of functions, use `nm` command from binutils (`avr-nm` on AVR chips).